# Find the number of local Maxima in the function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

question is simple:

> Find the **number** of local maxima in the following function $$f(x)=\cos (2\pi x )+x-\{x\}$$:where {...} represents fractional part of $x$, in the interval $[0,10]$

I plotted the graph and got answer $9$ but i am not sure whether i am correct or not.

And is there any other way of solving this question without graph/?

Comment: @Moo you can see where the function breaks(where it get discontinuous) those are maxima, aren't they?

Answer (score 1):

Fractional part can be written $$\{ x \}=x-[x]$$
where $[\ ]$ is floor function, e.g. $[2.3]=2, [5.6]=5$.
The objective function can thus be written, $$f(x)=\cos (2\pi x)+[x]$$
As $\cos ()$ function is capped between $[-1,+1]$, to find the maximum, you should focus on the last interval $[9,10]$

For $[9,10]$, the objective function is $$f(x)=\cos (2\pi x)+9$$. To find the optimal, $$f^{'}(x)=0$$ or $$\sin (2\pi x)=0$$ Within $[9,10]$, there are two points 9 and 9.5, where 9 is the local maximum and 9.5 is the local minimum.

Comment: "$f(x)=cos(2πx)+[x]$" shouldn't it be $f(x)=cos(2\pi x)+x-[x]$

Comment: @DeNiSkA $x= [x]+\{x\}$ which implies $x-\{x\}= [x]$